# Provider could not be resolved exception using EFE with EF Core and SQLite

Tags: entity-framework-extensions

I'm just trying to evaluate EFE to see if it can provide some performance improvements for me.

To do so I've created a simple dotnet core console app using EF Core 2.0.1 with SQlite (Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite) and added the Z.EntityFramework.Extensions.EFCore package v2.0.10.

In my DbContext.OnConfiguring I do the following:

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Filename=test.db");
```

But when I call context.BulkInsert I get the following exception:

> The Provider could not be resolved. You must explicitly set the
>   Provider.

Can you tell me what I am missing please? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello JohnB, The answer has been updated. EFE Core now support SQLite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** Updating answer with newly provided supported

SQLite is now supported since 2018-02-05 for **EFE Core**

The EF Core version support now:

- SQL Server
- SQL Azure
- PostgreSQL
- MySQL
- SQLite